# How to start thread from another definition and stop thread from another definition in python?

Tags: python, flask

The current behaviour is that whenever `Question` endpoint will be from webpage then t1 thread and t2 thread will run but I want the behaviour to be whenever `done` endpoint is called,  both thread should stop
both the definition is different.
how can I do this?

```
@app.route('/Question')
def Question():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=demoTask,args=())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=demoTask1,args=())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    return render_template('questions.html')

@app.route('/done')
def done():
     return render_template('done.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer.**
we can create thread outside the definition in python.
and we can start from any definition and we can stop from any definition in python.
this is working for me.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=demoTask,args=())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=demoTask1,args=())
t3 = threading.Thread(target=demoTask2,args=())

@app.route('/instructions')
def instructions():
    return render_template('instructions.html')

@app.route('/thankyou')
def thankyou():
    return render_template('thankyou.html')

@app.route('/Question')
def Question():
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    return render_template('questions.html')

@app.route('/done')
def done():

    t3.start()
    return render_template('done.html')
```